# How to install custom encoding to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, encoding, eclipse-plugin

How can I ship custom encoding with an eclipse product. I have created a plugin for it and then I use the xbootpath in order to inject the jar file.

I want to simplify that by integrating the encoding in my product. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to give us a lot more information about what you mean by 'custom encoding' because at the moment it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: There is a jar file with a proprietary charset encoding called s3.  So there is an encoder/decoder and charset provider and everything works fine. My question is how to integrate that encoding in my eclipse product?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse just uses the standard `Charset` class and as I can't see any  support for integrating addition `CharsetProvider` classes.

Comment: yeah It is possible as I described in my question with Xbootclasspath, but I couldn't find an extension point to attach it directly. What I do is that I add the charset as plugin and then in the eclipse.ini I add the jar to the XBootclasspath,

But as I said before, it's not the best solution..